# Laravel validation - different array fields not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I'm using Laravel 7. Let's say I have this color drop down: Yellow, Blue, Orange, Black etc. These are not stored in the database.

In the form I have favorite colors and least favorite colors, each field can select more than 1 color. Ie. my favorite colors can be blue and yellow and my least favorite colors can be black. Both fields are array fields (favorite_colors[], least_favorite_colors[])

In my laravel validation, I want to make sure colors cannot be consisted in both favorite colors and least favorite colors. ie. If I add blue as my favorite color, blue cannot be in my least favorite color list.

I have tried:

```
[...
'favorite_colors'   => 'required|array',
'favorite_colors.*' => 'required|different:least_favorite_colors.*', /*not working */
...]
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a use case for the not in validation rule.

> not_in:foo,bar,...
>   The field under validation must not be included in the given list of values. The Rule::notIn method may be used to fluently construct the rule:...

So you should check that each value in the favorite colors array is not in the least favorite colors array.

```
[...
'favorite_colors' => 'required|array|distinct',
'favorite_colors.*' => 'required|notIn::{$this->input("least_favorite_colors")}'
```

- Haven't tested this

Different is used to compare a field to another field. To use different you would have to check in some sort of loop against each least favorite color.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input @Haze, the correct way of using it was:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

and validation like this:

```
'favorite_colors.*' => ['required', Rule::notIn($request->post('least_favorite_colors'))],
```

If using

```
'favorite_colors.*' => 'required|different:least_favorite_colors.*',
```

It will only compare favorite_colors array 0 with least_favorite_colors array 0, array 1 with array 1 etc.